# Rotate subplot xaxis location

Tags: python, matplotlib, rotation

I have two subplots on one figure.  Im plotting time (00:12:32) on the x-axis and I would like to rotate the xticks of both subplots but when I use the code below, only the one subplots ticks are rotated.

```
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

Here is the full code:

```
#print(start_event_arr)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20.0, 20.0))
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(20.0, 20.0))

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2)
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(2,1,1,sharex=ax)
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=6)


dates = [dateutil.parser.parse(s) for s in start_event_arr]
y = event_volume_sums
#plt.xticks(rotation=90)

ax.set_xticks(dates)
ax.plot(dates, cumulative_vol_arr)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%H:%M:%S'))
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MinuteLocator(interval=30))
ax.tick_params(axis='x', which='major', labelsize=10)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)

cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet')
ax1.scatter(dates,y,s=event_duration_secs*500, c=event_duration_secs,cmap=cm,linewidth=0,alpha=1.0)
ax1.grid()

#plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.show()
```

I suspects the problem is how i define the subplots but I dont know how to fix it. saying ax.xticks() isnt possible.
Thank you.

Comment: I would be nice if you could provide sample data to play with your code. `plt.xticks` refers to `plt.gca()` (**g**et **c**urrent **a**xis; the most recently created axis) to change the xticks there. I guess you have to apply the rotation also to the other axis object. Sharing an axis does not mean that everything is shared. Visual representation can be configured independently.

Comment: Even though I can't run you code, form what I see, you have two figures and two subplot axes in each one. When you call  `plt.xticks` it will apply the change only to the active axis. To make any of the other axes active you can call `plt.sca(ax)` or `plt.sca(ax1)` depending on which one you want to alter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set the rotation to both axes. One option would be to use

```
plt.setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
plt.setp(ax1.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90)
```

You should also be able to change the rotation for all subplots within each figure

```
fig.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)
fig1.autofmt_xdate(rotation=90)
```

Comment: Instead of writing thank you you may always just upvote. (same with just any question or answer you find useful or that has helped you here on SO).